# Laravel Model: Average of a referenced model (sub query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to get the average of a referenced model's column. I have a comic database which contains comics and each comic has a rating. Every comic belongs to a series. The model `Series` should be able to get the average of all according comics. As a result i consider this the quality of the whole comic series.

I'm working with this database schema and an according laravel model `Series`.

[image: database schema]

## Series.php

```php
  \\ [...]

  public function comics()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Comic::class, 'series_id', 'series_id');
  }
```

## What I've tried

I tried adapting a subselect i saw in a Laracon lesson by Jonathan Reinink, which is working in another case where i try to find the first comic of a series (Requirement 3 of https://github.com/reinink/laracon2018):

### Series.php

```php
public function scopeWithAverageRating($query)
  {
    // using a Builder::macro in AppServiceProvider.php
    $query->addSubSelect(
      'rating',
      Comic::select('comic_id')
        ->whereRaw('series_id = series.series_id')
        ->avg('comic_rating')
    );
  }
```

### AppServiceProvider.php

```php
Builder::macro('addSubSelect', function ($column, $query) {
  if (is_null($this->getQuery()->columns)) {
    $this->select($this->getQuery()->from . '.*');
  }
  return $this->selectSub($query->limit(1)->getQuery(), $column);
});
```

But in tinker shell i only get a SQL-error:

```
>>> $s = new App\Series;
>>> $s->withAverageRating();

Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'series.series_id' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select avg(`comic_rating`) as aggregate from `comics` where series_id = series.series_id)'
```

I guess I'm completly lost and not sure whether i chose the right way in the first place. I hope you can give an advise/hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at JOINs In MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't understand the problem, it's solved if i don't use the eloquent `avg` method and replace it with a `selectRaw`:

```php
public function scopeWithAverageRating($query)
{
  $query->addSubSelect(
    'rating',
    Comic::selectRaw('avg(comic_rating)')
      ->whereRaw('series_id = series.series_id')
  );
}
```